# Remove trailing slash Lighttpd url

Tags: lighttpd, rewrite

A weird request, but I really need this answered. Can you guys help me using re-write rules to remove the trailing slash from urls in Lighttpd.conf?

EG:

```
**A** www.example.com/page/
**B** www.example.com/page
```

I want url A to be forced into the semantics of url B.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do sounds ***wrong***. The web-server does not handle the request urls that the browser sees. This is an application issue. Your web-application needs to present the urls in the form of `www.example.com/page` instead of `www.example.com/page/` that it does now.

If you do not want to change the application but still want this desired behaviour, you may want to consider using a filtering proxy in front of lighty and then filtering all the returned links.

Comment: The trouble is if you don't have a web application, and you're just serving static files. Then URLs are indeed entirely the server's responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Not really to the point, but you might want to have [the reverse effect](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/load_no11.htm)...

Anyways, as far as lighttpd code goes, that *would be* something like this:

```
url.redirect = ( "/page/" => "/page" )
url.rewrite-once = ( "/page" => "/page/" )
```

but, since "/page" doesn't find a file and tries the directory "/page/" (and the rewrite seems to do nothing to hide that), that does produce a redirect-loop.

Then your real question would be: is it possible to tell lighttpd not to redirect on directories? That, unfortunately, I didn't find a way to do... but I didn't search in deep, in fact I do prefer URLs with trailing slashes (also visually)...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want the request `/foo/bar` to serve `/foo/bar/index.html`, and `/foo/bar/` to redirect to `/foo/bar`. Then you can say:

```
url.redirect = ("^/foo/bar/$" => "/foo/bar")
url.rewrite-once = ("^/foo/bar$" => "/foo/bar/index.html")
```

Rewriting directly to the index file instead of to `/foo/bar/`, and anchoring the redirect regex with `$`, avoids triggering the redirect rule after the rewrite.